# Stacked Column Chart With Unequal SubGroups in HighCharts.js

Tags: highcharts

I am attempting to create a stacked column chart with an unequal number of "sub-groups".

For example, given the following data:

```
Category#1 : [SubCategory1: 2, SubCategory2: 4, SubCategory3: 3], 
Category#2 : [SubCategory4: 5, SubCategory5: 3], 
Category#3 : [SubCategory6: 4, SubCategory7: 3, SubCategory8: 3, SubCategory9: 5]
...
```

I want to create a column chart where the first column is comprised of three stacked segments and has a total height of 9,
the second column has a stack of two segments with total height of 8,
and the third column has four segments with a total height of 15.

After having worked for a little while with the HighCharts API and generally getting good results, I believe what I want to accomplish is probably doable and I am likely just missing some combination of options or structuring my data incorrectly. Does anyone know what I need to do in order to create such a chart?

Comment: How about using `null` values in your data?

Comment: @Ondkloss Could you give me an example of how that would look?

Comment: May have misunderstood your situation, but something like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afmpu54k/)

Comment: @Ondkloss It seems a bit difficult when none of the columns share any of the subcategories in common, as you end up with a lot of series with mostly null values. It might be feasible, but I was hoping to do something more along the lines of point data configuration.

Comment: Alright. Something like this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afmpu54k/1/)

Comment: @Ondkloss Much more usable! I did not realize you use a numerical x-axis value with a categorical x-axis, I think part of my issue was trying get to match up using a 'name' attribute for the datapoints. Would you consider making this an answer?

Comment: Good to hear! I'll write an answer to include some more detail for other potential readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two of the ways you can solve this are:

---

1. Giving each point in your series a specific `x` index that relates to the category index.

   Example of a series ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afmpu54k/1/)):

   ```
   series: [{
       name: 'John',
       data: [{x:0,y:5},{x:3,y:7},{x:4,y:2}]
   }
   ```

   Here we skip the 2nd and 3rd category (index 1 and 2), so they will not have a value.

---

2. Using `null` values in your series to skip having it appear in a category.

   Example of a series ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afmpu54k/)):

   ```
   series: [{
       name: 'John',
       data: [5, null, null, 7, 2]
   }
   ```

   This series also skips the 2nd and 3rd category, like the one above.

---

Your solution choice may rely on how many `null` values you would end up with. If it is only a few, then that might be the most lightweight solution. If it is a lot, then using Point objects with `x` values may be more suitable and cleaner.